# Can adding two rational points on an elliptic curve yield an integral point?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E : y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ be an elliptic curve with $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$. We know that by [the group law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law), the set of rational points in $E$ forms an abelian group with $+$ as in defined in the link above.

Let $P, Q \in E$ be two points in $E$ such that one of them has rational but non-integral coordinates. Is it possible that $P + Q$ has integral coordinates? What if we restrict it to $P + P$, where $P$ has coordinates in $\Bbb{Q} \setminus \Bbb{Z}$? Trying out some examples seems to show that $P + Q$ can't have integral coordinates, but I can't seem to prove it using elementary methods.

**Context**: This problem is related to an attempt to show that an integral point $P$ is not torsion if $P + P$ does not have integral coordinates (not sure if this is even true). If the statement above holds, then this follows easily. Perhaps there is a much easier way to do this?

Comment: Take $Q = -P + R$, where $R$ is any integral point.

Comment: I recalled a cute related question. [In this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2409747/11619) we see an example of a situation where doubling an integral point does not give another integral point, **but tripling does**!

Answer (score 6):

Reiterating my comment from above, take $Q = -P + R$, where $R$ is any integral point for counterexamples to the first question.

For the case of $P + P$, then the answer is yes. Take $E: y^2 = x^3 + \frac{1}{4} x$. Then $E(\mathbf{Q})_\mathrm{tor} \cong \mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}$ and is generated by $P = \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right) \in E(\mathbf{Q}\setminus \mathbf{Z})$, but $2P = (0, 0)$.

Comment: Why does it follow from Siegel's theorem?

Comment: I do not see how it follows from Ziegel's theorem. By that theorem the set of integral points is finite. But it is not necessarily a subgroup. So it is not necessarily true that every integral point is torsion.

Comment: I also do not believe  a reduction modulo a prime (good or bad) can prove that some point is integral.

Comment: It absolutely can. See the answer here, for example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242875/an-example-of-all-non-torsion-rational-points-on-an-elliptic-curve-are-integral. I took out the bit about Siegel's Theorem, as it's a more complicated argument anyway.

Comment: @JCAA [Carl Ludwig Siegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Ludwig_Siegel), but not "Ziegel".

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't thinking clearly about this earlier. Took out the result under the assumption $a,b \in \mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: Of course what only matters is how he himself spelled his name. And that was Siegel. In general Ziegel is the German ( more precisely Yiddish) version of the Jewish last name Segal. In Russian (my first language) it is Зигель with the first letter "З", which is "Z".

Comment: @BrandonCarter: Using prime reduction one can prove that a point is **not** integral (see Lubin's answer in your link) by showing that some prime is in the denominator, but you cannot prove that some point is integral because $1/3=2 \mod 5$.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I am actually restricting $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$ (the question has been edited). How does the link in your comment above answer my question? Apologies for I'm relatively new to elliptic curve theory.

Answer (score 3):

Take any integral point $P$ and any rational non-integral point $Q$ such that $P-Q$ is not integral ( these are easy to find since the set of integrl points is finite). Then $P=Q+(P-Q)$.

Comment: Right, why didn't I see that. But what about the case for $P + P$?

Comment: I do not know about $P+P$. I believe an example exists but one has to consider concrete curves.

Comment: The formula for $P+P$ where $P=(x,y)$ is $2P = (\lambda^2-2x, \lambda(3x -\lambda^2) -y)$ where $\lambda  = (3x^2 + a)/(2y)$ if the curve is $y^2=x^3+ax+b$. So there is no reason to believe that $P+P$ is always not integral if $P$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an easy way to see that if $P$ has nonintegral coordinates, then $[2](P)$ may well have integral coordinates:

I’ll show that the contrapositive of your proposed proposition is false. This says: if $Q$ has coordinates in $\Bbb Z$, then all four $P$ with $[2](P)=Q$ have coordinates in $\Bbb Z$. But if that were true, then there would be infinitely many points with $\Bbb Z$-coefficients, well known to be false.

(I recognize that the above argument is not self-contained, needing as it does support from fairly advanced theorems on elliptic curves. I’ll let others fill in the details, if they’re so inclined.)

(**Note to Edit**): I thank @ user760870 for making clear that my use of the word “integral” was imprecise.

Comment: This is a little strange because there need not be any points $P \in E(\mathbf{Q})$ with $2P=Q$.

Comment: If $E$ is in minimal Weierstrass form over $\mathbf{Q}$, then a point $P = [x,y]$ is integral if and only if there are no primes $p$ dividing the denominator, equivalently, if and only if the reduction modulo $p$ of $P$ is not equal to $\infty \in E/\mathbf{F}_p$ for every $p$. But if $P$ is non-integral, then $P = \infty \mod p$ for some $p$, and then $2P = \infty \mod p$ as well, and so it seems that $2P$ (and $nP$ for any $n \ge 2$) cannot be integral.

Comment: Absolutely correct, @user760870 , because I was imprecise in my use of the word “integral”. What I meant instead was “with both coordinates in $\Bbb Z$.” I will edit to make my answer more precise.

Comment: And now I see that my answer above is beside the point, because OP was quite explicit in specifying that the original point should have *rational* coordinates, not all integral.

Comment: Dear @Lubin, sorry to complain again, but I still have problems with your answer. You say "all four $P$ with $[2]P = Q$". Now for a typical $Q$ the points $P$ need not have rational coefficients, so the contrapositive is empty in this case.

Comment: Yes, @user760870 , that’s exactly why my answer is not an answer to the question as (now?) posed. Did OP change it along the way? Anyway, if my answer here had not acquired a couple of brownie points, I would have deleted it.